# Java Paint Error Setting Up

Tags: java, paint

The problem is simple:

I get the error "***void is an invalid type for the variable paint***".

```
public void paint(Graphics g){

}
```

I could not find a solution on the web.I have used the method before, so I have no idea what could be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message indicates that the method is located within another method. Move the method out of that method so that it located at the same level.

Comment: Probably something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14172262/solvedvoid-is-an-invalid-type-for-the-variabl